# If a website filters out XSS-related terms, is it still potentially vulnerable?

Tags: xss, javascript, html

For example, say there is a website where the user input is not properly sanitized, but these filters are still active. Anything typed is inserted into between two div tags.

If the input is "`hello`", it shows up in the source as "`<div>hello</div>`"

Tags also work. If the input is "`<!--`", then it would turn into 
"`<div><!--</div>`", turning much of the HTML on the page into a comment, breaking part of it.

However, script tags are filtered out. Inputting "`<script>alert('xss')</script>`" will return "`<div>alert('xss')</div>`", obviously not executing any javascript.

"javascript:" is filtered and turned into "nojavascript" if used as a source.

input:

`<img src=javascript:alert('hi'); />`

output:

`<img src=nojavascript...alert('hi'); />`

Another part of the filter protects it from "`onload=`" and other HTML event-based XSS attacks. If "`onload=alert('xss')`" is the input, it will not show up at all in the source.

So, my question is, would this website still be vulnerable to cross-site scripting, or is it safe due to the filter it uses?

Comment: do you tackle onerror onclick onhover and all too?

Comment: Yep, those are also filtered out. If the input is "on...=", it is ignored.

Comment: Do you filter by parsing the XML tree or regex-based?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So, my question is, would this website still be vulnerable to cross-site scripting, or is it safe due to the filter it uses?

**It's not safe.** You didn't fully describe your filtering mechanism, but a blacklist-based XSS filter is guaranteed to leave some loopholes.

### Examples

Do you consider the `href` attribute of link tags? A click on this link would trigger:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">Click me<a>
```

If you filter out `javascript:`, are your checks case-insensitive?

```
<a href="JaVaScRiPt:alert(1)">Click me<a>
```

And do you consider different ways of encoding? E.g.:

```
<a href="javascript&#x3a;alert(1)">Click me</a>
```

Do you consider frames? It's certainly not enough to filter out `javascript:` since an attacker could also use other schemes, e.g.:

```
<iframe src="data:text/html,<script>alert(1)</script>">
```

If you're thinking that the `<script>` tag inside the frame `src` would be detected by your filter - it can of course be encoded, e.g.:

```
<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgxKTwvc2NyaXB0Pg==">
```

Also, do you consider that `<iframe>` has a `srcdoc` attribute?

```
<iframe srcdoc="<script>alert(1)</script>">
```

Again, there are many ways to encode this, e.g.:

```
<iframe srcdoc="&#x3C;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3E;&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3E;">
```

The list goes on. (What about SVGs, forms, meta tags, obscure vendor-specific protocols, embedded flash applets, CSS, ... ?)

The correct approach is to use a whitelist of allowed tags and attributes, and parsing the resulting DOM tree instead of regex-based string replacements.